# How to open source code files from my application in eclipse?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

I am using `spring-boot` for building my application in my organization. While going through some of the tutorial videos on `spring-boot`, I have seen the tutor opening the source code files by typing <kbd>ctrl+shift+N</kbd> from a sample project in IntelliJ Idea.

I am using spring-boot and maven with STS.

I can open the source code in STS by doing <kbd>F3</kbd> on the class name and not by <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+R</kbd>. I want to open these files in STS by shortcuts like the person in the video did on IntelliJ. The source jars are already downloaded from maven central.

Anything I can do in STS to achieve this?

Comment: Control + click on the class name? Or in Mac command + click

Comment: That I can open via F3. I am talking about the class that I have not used in my code. Some random file present in some spring boot jar, could be some txt file or any other file.

Comment: Mmh I am still confused. Anyway, for classes you should use control + shift+ T. T of type. R is for resources, like properties file and other.

Comment: I don’t think you understand. Try opening spring.factories present in spring-boot-autoconfigure.jar.

Comment: In your second comment you said "class I have not used". I don't think spring.factories is a class. That is why I told you to use control+shift+T. Anyway now I understand and I don't know how to do that. What is your use case? Maybe if I understand it I can help in some other way